# JQuery click event not targeting div children

Tags: jquery

I have a problem which seems simple, but I can't seem to find a solution. I basically have a div which triggers a click event. My html is:

```
  <li class="infobox">
      <a href="#"><img class="thumb" src="img/2.jpg" alt="image02" /></a>
      <div class="over">
        <img src="img/search_icon.png" alt="read more" />
         <h6>New business</h6>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
       </div>
   </li>
```

and my jquery code is:

```
$('#news_gallery li .over').click(function(event) {
   // I have animation code here
});
```

The problem is this: the function works fine, except for the fact the click event does not work on the img or any of the text that is within the div '.over'.  Why are the child elements not passed to the click event? Do I need to pass special parameters to the function?

Comment: hm it should... the bubbling will reach `.over` if you click on the descendants

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/mUK7N/3/

Comment: by the way, maybe your markup should include `#news_gallery` and the `ul` container of that `li`

Comment: Are you adding LIs with Ajax?

Comment: and make sure that in the `click` handler, you don't have a call to `e.stopPropagation()`

Comment: No, the list is not being added via Ajax. The div class `over` is hidden, then revealed on thumbnail rollover with jquery. No call to `e.stopPropagation()` either. As @NiftyDude mentioned, `#news_gallery` is the calss of the ul. Funny how the jsfiddle provided by @Tats_innit does work though.

Comment: @user1391152 Magic lol, you might try copy pasting the code from fiddle. :)

Comment: After some serious debugging, I've found that the reason for this is because of a `.clone()` event within the function. This is obviously a totally different problem altogether which I will create a new post for.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the div content is dynamic. When the contents are loaded after setting the event, the newly inserted elements don't have any associated events.  A quick fix is to use 
"live" instead of "click"

```
$('#news_gallery li .over').live('click',function(event) {
   // I have animation code here
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try following:

```
<li class="infobox">
      <a href="#"><img class="thumb" src="img/2.jpg" alt="image02" /></a>
      <div class="over">
        <img src="img/search_icon.png" alt="read more" />
         <h6>New business</h6>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
       </div
</li>
```

and js:

```
$('.infobox .over').click(function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```